# Mysql 5.7 delete 2 related table using join does not work

Tags: mysql

Trying to delete 2 related tables using JOIN and get this error.
Anything wrong with my query?

But If I delete them separately first product_spec_entry  and then product_specification works fine.

SQL:

```
delete ps, pse 
from product_specification ps inner join product_spec_entry pse 
on pse.product_specification_id=ps.id 
where ps.product_code='VHG-Z20-W3';
```

Error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`custom_quotes_temp_2`.`product_spec_entry`, CONSTRAINT `FKc50kwnlefgubr1t6uevjh23rh` 
FOREIGN KEY (`product_specification_id`) REFERENCES `product_specification` (`id`))
```

[image]

Comment: Switch it: `delete pse, ps ...`

Comment: Thx I tried it did nt work. Could it be coz of the old version of msql 5.7

Comment: No, that is not the problem. BTW if you define the table reference as ON DELETE CASCADE then all `product_spec_entry` records will be deleted automatically when you delete a `product_specification`